# NullPointerException in SQLite database at line 71

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-xml

I am developing an application whereby I am storing and retrieving data from database. The data is  retrieved by randomly choosing id ('id' is the primary key constrained column in the table), storing in cursor object and displaying along with radio buttons. One of these Radio Buttons is then selected by the user and accordingly the result is displayed.

I have implemented this as  (code : DBHelperDisplay.java) :

```
package course.examples.jumboquest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
//import java.io.*;
//import java.lang.*;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
//import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
//import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DBHelperDisplay extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView tv; 
DBHelper myDB;
RadioGroup radioChoices;
RadioButton rbtChoice; 
Button btSubmit;
String choice1;
String choice2;
String choice3;
String choice4;
String strAns;
CustomTimer cdt;
TextView quest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dbhelper_display);
    
    cdt = new CustomTimer(20000, 1000);
    cdt.start();
    
    myDB = new DBHelper(this);
    
    myDB.insertQuestion(1, "who is the team member whose name starts with s?", "Vinita", "Akanksha", "Swati", "Megha", "Swati");
    myDB.insertQuestion(2, "who is the team member whose name starts with m?", "Vinita", "Akanksha", "Swati", "Megha", "Megha");
    myDB.insertQuestion(3, "who is the team member whose name starts with a?", "Vinita", "Akanksha", "Swati", "Megha", "Akanksha");
    myDB.insertQuestion(4, "who is the team member whose name starts with v?", "Vinita", "Akanksha", "Swati", "Megha", "Vinita");
    myDB.insertQuestion(5, "who is the team member whose name ends with i?", "Vinita", "Akanksha", "Swati", "Megha", "Swati");
    
    Cursor rs = myDB.getData();
    rs.moveToFirst();
    String Question = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.Col_Ques));
    choice1 = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.Col_Choice1));
    choice2 = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.Col_Choice2));
    choice3 = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.Col_Choice3));
    choice4 = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.Col_Choice4));
    strAns = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.Col_Ans));
    
    
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timertxt);
    
  quest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quest);
  quest.setText(Question);
    
    //final TextView ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
    
    Button btClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btClear);
    btClear.setText("CLEAR");     // Line 71
   
   addListenerRadioChoices() ;
    
   btClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v) {
        //ans.setText("");
            
       }
  });
 }
   public void addListenerRadioChoices(){ 
    
    radioChoices = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioChoices);
        
    ((RadioButton) radioChoices.getChildAt(0)).setText(choice1); 
    ((RadioButton) radioChoices.getChildAt(1)).setText(choice2);
    ((RadioButton) radioChoices.getChildAt(2)).setText(choice3);
    ((RadioButton) radioChoices.getChildAt(3)).setText(choice4);
        
    btSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btSubmit); 
    btSubmit.setText("SUBMIT");
    btSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v) {
        
        int selected = radioChoices.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        rbtChoice = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected); 
        String Ans = rbtChoice.getText().toString();
         if(Ans.equalsIgnoreCase(strAns)){
            
            cdt.cancel();
            //ans.setText(" ANSWER");
            
         }
   
        
    }
   });
  } 

public class CustomTimer extends CountDownTimer{
    //TextView ed;
    public CustomTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval){
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
        //current = millisUntilFinished/1000;
        tv.setText("Time Left:" + millisUntilFinished/1000);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        tv.setText("Time Up - lost the game!");
    }
}

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    
    public static final String Database_Name = "Questions.db"; 
    public static final String Table_Name = "Comics"; 
    public static final String Col_ID = "id"; 
    public static final String Col_Ques = "question"; 
    public static final String Col_Choice1 = "choice1"; 
    public static final String Col_Choice2 = "choice2"; 
    public static final String Col_Choice3 = "choice3"; 
    public static final String Col_Choice4 = "choice4"; 
    public static final String Col_Ans = "answer"; 
    
    public DBHelper(Context context){
        super(context, Database_Name, null, 4);
    }
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
       String   CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Table_Name + "( " + Col_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + Col_Ques + " TEXT, " + Col_Choice1 + " TEXT, "
                                + Col_Choice2 + " TEXT, " + Col_Choice3 + " TEXT, " + Col_Choice4 + " TEXT, " + Col_Ans + " TEXT );" ;
       db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
       
    }   
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Comics");
          onCreate(db);
    }
    
    public boolean insertQuestion(int id, String question, String choice1, String choice2, String choice3, String choice4, String answer){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    
        contentValues.put("id",id);
        contentValues.put("question",question);
        contentValues.put("choice1",choice1);
        contentValues.put("choice2",choice2);
        contentValues.put("choice3",choice3);
        contentValues.put("choice4",choice4);
        contentValues.put("answer",answer);
        db.insert("Comics", null, contentValues);
        db.close();
        return true;
    }
    public Cursor getData(){
    //public void getData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        int numRows = (int)DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,Table_Name);
        //System.out.println(numRows);
        int min = 1;
        int max = numRows;
        Random r = new Random();
        int id = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    //  Cursor res= db.rawQuery("Select * from Comics", null);
    //  ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor res= db.rawQuery("Select * from Comics where id = '" + id + "'", null);
        /*res.moveToFirst();
          while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
          array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(Col_ID)));
          res.moveToNext();
          }
          //quest.setText("");
         StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
          for(int i= 0; i<array_list.size();i++){
              text.append(array_list.get(i).toString() + "\n");
          }
         quest.setText(text.toString());*/
    return res;
    }
}
}
```

My dbhelper_display.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timertxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioChoices"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbtChoice1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbtChoice2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbtChoice3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbtChoice4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    
</RadioGroup>

 <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ans"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting NullPointerException on implementing the above code. I have attached the LOgCat for the same.

Log Cat result :

```
10-24 07:57:44.567: D/dalvikvm(1498): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 91K, 5% free 3265K/3432K, paused 80ms, total 81ms
10-24 07:57:45.107: D/gralloc_goldfish(1498): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-24 07:57:51.387: D/AndroidRuntime(1498): Shutting down VM
10-24 07:57:51.387: W/dalvikvm(1498): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a47ba8)
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498): Process: course.examples.jumboquest, PID: 1498
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{course.examples.jumboquest/course.examples.jumboquest.DBHelperDisplay}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at course.examples.jumboquest.DBHelperDisplay.onCreate(DBHelperDisplay.java:71)
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     ... 11 more
10-24 07:57:55.767: I/Process(1498): Sending signal. PID: 1498 SIG: 9
```

What is the error in implementing database?  Also, earlier it was showing the error 'cursor index requested -1 with size 1'. I did some changes and now it is showing the above error. What should be done in the previous case too if that error comes again? I am new to SQLite databases in Android.

Comment: well.. wat at `DBHelperDisplay.java:71` ??

Comment: post the line 71 in DBHelperDisplay.java file

Comment: The log is very clear - `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 07:57:51.437: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at course.examples.jumboquest.DBHelperDisplay.onCreate(DBHelperDisplay.java:71)`

Comment: check whether button with ID: btClear is mentioned in dbhelper_display.layout

Comment: @POOJAGUPTA we need to know wats line of code is at line number 71. you have posted the log cat :-/ i can see the logcat above in your question.

Comment: @Panther : in the code I have written in comments as '//71' see that .

Comment: as per the post here the line 71 seems to be a comment `//final TextView ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);` :-/

Comment: @POOJAGUPTA Simple spelling mistake. Change `R.id.btClear` to `R.id.btnClear`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect this is a typo, that you do not have a Button with an `android:id="@+id/btClear` inside of your dbhelper_display.xml layout file. Based on the fact that you were able to compile, I suspect that you have that ID in a different file, but not in dbhelper_display.xml.

From your posted XML code, I see this:

```
android:id="@+id/btnClear"
```

The Java Code says this:

```
Button btClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btClear);
```

Make these consistent, and it will work. Also check your `btnSubmit`, which I believe has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the line `Button btClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btClear);`. What happens if it can't find the view at that id? It would try and cast null to Button and then set btClear to `null`. You then try `btClear.setText("CLEAR");`. You can't invoke methods on null objects, so it would throw NullPointerException.

Try looking at the value of `btClear` in between those lines. It will most likely be null.

Edit: Upon OP posting new information, it apepars that `btClear` should actually be `btnClear` as described by `android:id="@+id/btnClear"`. This should resolve the issue by correcting `R.id.btClear` to `R.id.btnClear`

Note: I'm assuming that the `**` in `**btClear.setText("CLEAR");` is a typo in your question formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Its a simple spelling mistake. You have written `R.id.btClear` in `Button btClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btClear);` you have to write `R.id.btnClear` :-/